# Automatically inserted Template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

A few days I literally ***discovered*** a behaviour of C++, where template arguments are automatically inserted, as shown in this example (nonsensical, only used to show what I mean):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Type> void setVar(Type& subj, const Type& in)
{
    subj = static_cast<Type>(in);
}

int main()
{
    int foo;
    setVar(foo, 42);
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

My questions:

- What is this behaviour called?
- are there special rules when and why templates can be automatically inserted?

Comment: that's just standard templates... you don't have to call setVar<int> because the compiler can easily tell that foo is an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this behaviour called?

Template argument deduction.

> are there special rules when and why templates can be automatically inserted?

You cannot say like `templates are inserted`. Rather the types of parameters are automatically deduced from the arguments. When and how? That's what TAD is all about.

Check out section `14.8.2` in C++03

Comment: what is TAD? Wikipedia doesn't seem to know the answer either ;-)

Comment: @nebukadnezzar : Template Argument Deduction. `;)`

Answer (score 0):

It's called template argument deduction, and of course there are special rules. Many rules. In 14.8.2 of the standard [temp.deduct].

The summary version is that if there's a set of template arguments which allows the function to be called, then it will be called with those arguments. The complication is exactly what's allowed, and how to choose between possible alternatives.